# Hibernate HQL Query - Error getting data

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

I am trying to write a hibernate query that returns only enabled credentials for my application but with the below query, all apps are returned - enabled or disabled

The query is as follows

```
select distinct accountAccess.companyAccount.credentials from AccountAccess accountAccess join accountAccess.companyAccount.credentials loadedCredential55 where accountAccess.user.login='admin' and loadedCredential55.enabled=true;
```

Just some info
AccountAccess has different levels such as read/ write - hence the distinct keyword
Credentials is a set

Any suggestions on what I need to do in order to get this query functioning?

Answer (score 0):

Try it from the root object

"SELECT o FROM Credential o
WHERE o.companyAccount.accountAccess.user.login='admin'
AND o.enabled=true"

Comment: unfortunately its the same trying the query this way